# How to remove "\" from the query with Laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to remove slashes from the query so query should work fine.

```
$str= '1','2';

$users = User::findMany([$str]);
```

But when i echo the query i get this.

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('\'1\',\'2\'');
```

Now, how to remove these slashes from the query?

Comment: I think your string is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$str= '1','2'` is string then put this direct into query like:

```
$users = User::findMany([$str]);
```

If not the string then first remove single quotes using `str_replace` PHP method and explode the value to convert into array and pass:

```
$str = explode(',',str_replace("'","", $str));
$users = User::findMany($str);
```

Comment: Exactly this is what i was looking far ,Thank you@AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a string. You can just pass an array like this:

```
$ids = [1,2];
$users = User::find($ids);
```

Then you can iterate `$users` with en foreach or something else.

Comment: so you mean first i need to convert that string into array ?

Comment: That string (`$str= '1','2';`) as you've shown it in your code isn't valid PHP anyway

Answer (score 0):

The findMany function needs an array you passing a string change `$str` variable to

```
$str = ['1','2'];
```

Comment: i am still getting the same output

Answer (score 0):

if your string is like this :

```
$ids = '1,2';
```

then easily convert it in array with php explode function :

```
$ids = explodes(',',$ids);
```

now your string is an array

```
$ids = [1,2];
$users = User::whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
```

No loop needed, it will give you multiple results based on your multiple ids.
you can check the result like this :

```
dd($users->toArray());
```